# What is the tallest tower (AGL) identified on a sectional chart within the Class-E-to-surface airspace surrounding an airport in the US?

Tags: airport

What is the tallest tower (in terms of AGL) identified on a sectional chart within the Class-E-to-surface airspace surrounding an airport in the US?

For the purpose of the question, "within the Class-E-to-surface airspace surrounding an airport" means within the part of the sectional chart that lies within a dashed magenta line that completely encloses the airport and is not separated from the airport by another dashed magenta or blue line.  I.e. not including within Class-E-to-surface "extensions" that are separate from the Class-E-to-surface that actually surrounds the airport.

For simplicity, let's NOT include Class D or higher that reverts to Class-E-to-surface at night, etc.

"Tower" means any type of structure-- radio antennae, whatever-- that is depicted on the sectional chart with a tower symbol and has the AGL elevation of the top of the tower identified on the sectional chart.

Comment: Define "surrounding an airport". Are we talking 200 feet or 20 miles?

Comment: within the dashed magenta line-- I will clarify

Comment: I'm confused.  If there is a control tower (with only minor exceptions) the airspace would be Class D (when the twr is operating).  All of these locations (as far as I can tell) revert to class E when the twr is closed.  Or are you talking about any type of tower/structure (not necessarily a control tower)?

Comment: any type of tower.  I will clarify

Comment: The control tower at KPHX is 321 feet agl. But that is in Class B.  Confirm you only want towers in surface areas designated as Class E?

Comment: Confirm, but I'm changing to 700'.  300' AGL is too easy to find.  Question pertains to using drone to inspect towers but no need to get into that.  No more edits to this question I promise.

Comment: At [LBL](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.04766938481568,-100.96119689452274&chart=301&zoom=1), I see a tower 505 AGL.  That's the best I've found so far.

Comment: please do not edit the question in such a way that makes the answers already posted invalid.

Comment: Sorry, should have asked a new question.  Oh, I see you rolled it back.  Ok then, new question.

Comment: -- Note-- clearly this question has been answered.  I don't think it contributes much to our understanding of anything so I am going to hit the delete button. If moderators feel it should not be deleted then that's fine too, no problem.  Now I see I'm not allowed to-- ok very good.

Comment: This question has now been substantially edited in a way that changes its meaning but does not invalidate previous answers.  The edit was in response to suggestions from other users, to allow another question that seemed redundant to be deleted.

Comment: @quietflyer edit looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Winslow-Lindbergh Airport (Arizona): Tower east of the airport is 356 feet agl.

[image]

Comment: Looks like that might be just outside the edge but lets go for 700' AGL now.

Comment: I looked at the zoom wrong, probably is inside the edge, but let's go for 700' AGL now

Answer (score 1):

The airport [KLBL](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.04394265199759,-100.95996093260862&chart=301&zoom=1) has a tower marked as 505 AGL.   And another, just barely outside the space at 520 AGL.

That is the highest I've been able to locate.

[image: KLBL Obstruction]

Comment: This seems to be the highest we've found to date.